# How can I access an array passed from a method so as to rearrange it in the main method

Tags: java

```
public class ICT_Questions_34 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Index of Numbers");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        RandomNumber(n);// It returns n number of 2 digit numbers at here. 

System.out.println(myList.length);
System.out.println(myList[2]);
// there seems to be a problem here as the method I called prior this statements is as if it isn't working. What's the problem
    }

    public static int[] RandomNumber(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            System.out.println("PLEASE Enter Positive Number!");
        }
        int[] myList = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            int Values = (int) ((90 * Math.random()) + 10);
            System.out.print(Values + "\t");
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {

                myList[j] = Values;

            }

        }
        return myList;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly; do you mean that you want to use the value returned by `RandomNumber(n)` in your `main` method? If so, you can assign it to a variable like so: `int randomNumber = RandomNumber(n)` and then use `randomNumber`.

Comment: Note: only classes should start with capital letters

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the `int[] myList` is local to the method `public static int[] RandomNumber(int n)` so it cannot be accessed out side of that method.

But you are returning the array so you can access in the `main` method like `int[] myList = RandomNumber(n);` so you code will like.

```
public class ICT_Questions_34 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Index of Numbers");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        int[] myList = RandomNumber(n);// It returns n number of 2 digit numbers at here. 

        System.out.println(myList.length);
        System.out.println(myList[2]);
        // there seems to be a problem here as the method I called prior this statements is as if it isn't working. What's the problem
    }

    public static int[] RandomNumber(int n) {
        if (n < 0) {
            System.out.println("PLEASE Enter Positive Number!");
        }
        int[] myList = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            int Values = (int) ((90 * Math.random()) + 10);
            System.out.print(Values + "\t");
            for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {

                myList[j] = Values;

            }

        }
        return myList;
    }

}
```